# Magento 2 curl POST with JSON body

Tags: magento2, curl

i've tried to do some curl post to my other services using built in magento curl.

i already did this for the curl request

```
        $this->curl->post($url, $data);
```

yeah it's work but my data is change to url encoded style. my question is there any ways for me change the style from url encoded to Json Body request?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible in Magento by default (I'm not sure from what version, but PR was merged in March of 2018.)

Here is an example:

```
/** \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ClientInterface $client */
$this->client->setHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ]);

$this->client->post($url, $jsonString);
```

And just as a reference, here is the PR in question: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/8373

Answer (score 0):

Eventually it's worked using the basic Curl without using the magento curl

i am following this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get

and it works beautifully

Answer (score -1):

This happens when you make a curl request through magento:

vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php

```
protected function makeRequest($method, $uri, $params = [])
{
    $this->_ch = curl_init();
    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    if ($method == 'POST') {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    } elseif ($method == "GET") {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    } else {
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    }
...
```

`http_build_query` corrupts the format of the json. 
If you patiently read the function makeRequest(), you will be surprised that it is not possible to send json in the body or do PUT / DELETE / PATCH ... etc with params. Instead you can use the old one known

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://.../');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['a'=>'1', 'b'=>'2']));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($result === false) {
    return false;
} else {
    return $result;
}
```